# Regarding autocomplete textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

### ## Regarding autocomplete textbox ##

In below code i want autocomplete textbox first search from database ,if data not find from database then search from google api in asp.net, but in this case search data from databae and google api.

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
        $('#Address').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Root.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'Address':'" + document.getElementById('Address').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                        if (response(data.d) == null) {
                            var svalue = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('Address'));
                            var svalueBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(/** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(svalue));
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

```
<input id="Address" type="text" style="width: 305px" placeholder="From..."/>

[WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string Address)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Address from Locations where Address LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", Address);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["Address"].ToString());
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's not a clear question here. Is there an error? Is it a JS or ASP problem? Please clarify and I'll help you.

Comment: Not a clear question[Try here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) may work for you.

Comment: when i want to enter place name into textbox then hes suggest me place name first from database, if regarding place does not exist into database then suggest me place from google .

Comment: when there are no any records found in the table then i want to search from Google.

this is my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {};
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', InitializeMap);
    function InitializeMap() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.7679, 78.8718);
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 4,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var svalue = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>'));
        var svalueBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(/** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(svalue));
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
            debugger
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/bw.aspx/GetCustomers") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                    debugger
                        if (data.d.length == 0) {
                            $('.ui-autocomplete').hide();
                            InitializeMap();
                        }
                        else {
                            $(".pac-container").remove();
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('-')[0],
                                    val: item.split('-')[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                    debugger
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                    debugger
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
            debugger
                $("#<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfCustomerId" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</form>
```

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string[] GetCustomers(string prefix)
    {
        List<string> customers = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select Address,LocationID from Locations where " + "Address like @SearchText + '%'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        customers.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["Address"], sdr["LocationID"]));
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            return customers.ToArray();
        }
    }
```